# How to adapt the date format in the admin/content page?

Tags: 7, nodes

Each Article shows "Authored on YYYY-MM-DD" date per configured regional date format. e.g. 2015-05-14 00:00:00 +0100

However, the content listing at `admin/content` shows the `UPDATED` date as MM-DD-YYYY unlike anything else and is confusing to admins.

Users have no choice of Default Time / Region on the Drupal 7.37 site. 
Date and Time Long, Medium, Short formats are all `... YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 1):

Date (and time) formats can be configured via `admin/config/regional/date-time`. It can be used to specify the format for data types Long, Medium and Short.

Other tabs that are available on that same page:

- Formats (to define your own custom formats).
- Localize (for language specific tuning).
- Date Views (for date views specific to "day", "week" or "month").

Answer (score 1):

The content listing at `admin/content` shows the updated date as **Short** format.

You can change the SHORT format at `admin/config/regional/date-time` from MM-DD-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD or anything else you want and then the format of updated date at the `admin/content` will change.